is exclusion in the Mensa considered bullying at a university in Germany
I am a student of a German university.
I have been going to the Mensa (canteen) with a group of colleagues (other students) for a long time. Then some of them told that they don't want to come with me any more, and excluded me from the group chat on that (where we decide the time).
Not everyone in that group wants to exclude me. However, our professor said that the legal department of our university confirms that they can exclude me if they want. Is it legal? Our university accepted the AGG (non-discrimination act) in 2013.
Is going to the canteen considered a "private matter" or is it a clear exclusion?
In that group there were about 50 students, and I heard only from 3 students (who excluded me) that they don't want to go with me to the canteen. I really feel bad about that.

Why can't you attend the Mensa session without them? What has the canteen got to do with it? If it's an informal group, why shouldn't they decide to exclude you? What makes it bullying?

@WeatherVane: "Mensa" is a term in German for a university cafeteria or canteen. I don't think this has anything to do with the high IQ organization.

I have no idea why this has 4 downvotes.  The only comment asking for clarification has been answered. Seems to be a pretty clear question?

It's not quite clear to me why you think AGG applies - there are a couple of scopes on which the discrimination must be based, such as your religion, age, etc., and your question lists none of these.

@MisterMiyagi I answered it under a post below (can repeat if needed). I believe that one of the basis of the exclusion was my weak integration into the group because of the language barrier (they are German people and my language level is still too weak). Then, of course, it's easier to bully those people who are less integrated, have fewer friends, are harder to understand, etc.

@YaroslavNikitenko "can repeat if needed" Please [edit] the relevant information into the question instead. People should be able to get all the relevant facts by just reading the question itself. Note that using the applicable AGG keyword on top of describing the situation might be helpful as well.

germany
Some assumptions (and explanations for non-Germans):

Mensa is a canteen in universities. While students may get a discount there, it is normally open to the general public. But for obvious reasons, being on campus, it is normally filled with students of that university.

Bigger universities, especially if they have multiple buildings across town, may have more than one Mensa.

It is not mandatory to eat in any of the Mensas. You can eat anywhere you want, you can eat there, or bring your own meal or leave campus and do whatever else you want.

You are a student. You are not employed by anybody.

The other people in your group are students. They are not employed by anybody.


Where each of you goes for lunch is not mandated by anything. Not by a law, not by university rules or anything else. It is your private time and how you spend it is entirely up to you.
It is every persons free choice to meet with you, or not. The fact that they have done so in the past has no legal consequences for their decisions of the future.
The AGG is a law and while it is nice the university "accepted" it, it applies to them either way. However, the AGGs area is employment and surrounding activities. Neither one of you seems to be an employee or bound by rules. The only employer or entity making official rules here, the university, has not changed anything for you. You are still free to go eat at the Mensa just like before.
You have also failed to mention why you think the AGG would apply here, even if you were all employed by the same employer. While lunch break is mandatory in Germany, what each employee does on their break is not. The only way to apply the AGG there would be if work issues were discussed and you were excluded based on one of the criteria mentioned in the AGG. From your picture and description, I would exlude a few, but you would need to point out if any applies to you that we cannot guess.
So to sum this up: Not wanting to have lunch with you as a private person on private time is not a crime. Not even if they were all Xists and you are X (for whatever value of X mentioned in the AGG). It might feel bad or unfair to you and maybe it is. Life isn't fair.
But it is not illegal.

Thanks for the answer. Yes, bullying is not criminal in Germany. However, here I can read specifically that bullying can be "Social exclusion (e.g. from conversations, joint lunches, departmental meetings)" https://www.rexx-systems.com/news-en/bullying-in-the-workplace/ So at what point does it become a "working context", could you elaborate on that? Or is it decided individually? Or is my reference wrong in your opinion?

In our region NRW there is a law which says that students are also members of the University (https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_text_anzeigen?v_id=10000000000000000654 Hochschulgesetz, paragraph 9). That is why it seems that students/employers distinction is not important here.

And this is the document that was accepted by our university. In paragraph 1 they say that AGG applies to persons mentioned in par. 9 of the Hochschulgesetz (that is also to students). https://www.rwth-aachen.de/global/show_document.asp?id=aaaaaaaaaagnjkx

You have still not shown that a) any of the AGG applies to you (are you any of the protected classes and are you excluded because of that?) or that b) the university itself is discriminating against you. It seems as far as the university is concerned, all is fine. You can study, you can eat, whether you do that with your fellow students or alone is none of their concern, since your lunch is your very own private matter. They do not regulate it.

@YaroslavNikitenko The RWTH guidelines you linked to seem to also impose some AGG-like rules in the relationship between students. However, you would have to show that either your treatment accounts to Mobbing as defined in those guidelines, or that this is Discrimination due to a protected characteristic. But it seems neither is the case. The closest thing is "exclusion from conversations" but that likely only applies to course-relevant conversations, e.g. in a group project. Careful: if you try to force your way into that friend group, that might amount to Stalking under these guidelines.

@amon yes, you are right, they impose it also between students. Paragraph 1 ends with the sentence that it is applicable to the Campus territory (Hochschulgelände), which includes the Mensa. 1) why course-relevant conversations? Did you see the first link above on "social exclusion"? 2) you don't understand what stalking is, and this suggestion is offensive with respect to me. A necessary aim is "so that their lifestyle is seriously impaired or even
their safety is threatened", this is definitely not the case.

@nvoigt my question is basically why you state that Mensa is "a private matter", and the link above says that "social exclusion" is social. I believe that AGG applies to me, because I am a foreigner and my language is still weak. It is hard for me to get new friends and I know few people in Germany. Section 3, (2) of the AGG (a comment under a post below). However, belonging to the groups mentioned in the AGG is not necessary to be considered bullying (source: ‘Mobbing’: The German Law of Bullying, Philipp Fischinger, https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1908464).

"I am a foreigner and my language is still weak" that is not one of the groups protected by the AGG. The AGG also does not care whether it is hard for you. It is a law, it only cares if the requirements for the law are fullfilled. After all those comments and legal discussions, we are still missing the most basic facts: Why did they exclude you? The AGG would apply if they excluded you because of race or ethnicity, not nationality or language skills. I'm still not convinced the AGG applies to private lunches, but that is a secondary concern, we are still at "does it apply to you at all"?

Can you think of any reasons why they woulxn't want to spend their lunch time together with you?

They can deny to want to associate with you at lunch
Everybody in Germany has the freedom to state their opinion as long as they don't violate another's rights. (GG Art. 5) As long as the statement is not defamatory, that means, they can say "I do not wish to meet you for lunch at the mess hall" and there is nothing that can be done.
While everybody has the right to form an association or other group under GG Art. 9 (as long as all other laws are observed), a regular lunch group is not such an organization. Also, organizations can have rules that allow to remove members under their statutes. Using the § 314 BGB it is even possible if they do not have a written statute, as the law requires an organization to take at least a nominal membership fee. It is however clear, that a the student group meeting at lunch is not such an association, so neither Art. 9 GG nor § 314 BGB do apply - the gathering just dissolved in combination A and new gatherings in combinations B and C appear: those that include a specific person and those that don't.
AGG is part of the canon of employment law. As students are not employed, this makes the whole law inapplicable to the situation. Further, the lunch break is explicitly not work time, and regulating who you have to associate with during it would be an overreach of any employer and violate the worker's rights.
To sum it up: Who you have lunch with and who you don't have lunch with is a private matter.

Well, my point is that only a subgroup excludes me. Do they have that right to forbid me joining the large group? This looks aggressive And the majority of students are employees at our institute (which is a part of the University).

In essence: Yes, they can say "I don't privately associate with X and people that associate with X. Choose X or me." You have no legal right to demand private association with a private person on their private time - Lunch is private time.

@YaroslavNikitenko these are only interpersonal issues. Anyone in a group can say "I want/do not want us to do X." Each person of the group is free to decide if they agree or not. If one person in the group does not want to have lunch with you and the rest agrees, in the end everyone in the group is ok with you not going to the lunch (even if some of them only because they do not want conflict).

@SJuan76 this is not strictly interpersonal, for it involves other people. I agree that each person may avoid having lunches with me, but IMHO telling other people that they should not do it is too much. Section 17 AGG: "Social responsibility of involved parties (1) The... employers, employees and their representatives are required to become actively involved in achieving the goal set out in section 1 within the context of their duties and scope of action." (https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0094) So the Uni must actively discourage discrimination.

I seriously advise you to get some counseling. It seems to me that your expectations about how people behaves are rather unrealistic. Which might be a factor in why they no longer wnat to be with you. If you want people to hang around with you, seeking legal remedies is not the best way.

@SJuan76 Section 3: "(5) An instruction to discriminate against a person on any of the grounds referred to in section 1 is deemed to be discrimination." "(2) Indirect discrimination is taken to occur where an apparently neutral provision, criterion or practice is liable to put persons at a particular disadvantage compared with other persons on any of the grounds referred to in section 1" (https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_agg/englisch_agg.html#p0029). For me as a foreign person it is hard to make social contacts here, therefore my exclusion from colleagues is particularly bad for me.

@SJuan76 I understand what is happening informally. However, people should be professional and not exclude me due to private matters. And the Uni should not foster bullying/exclusion, but actively fight against that. Anyway my goal here is to better understand the applicable laws (thanks to everyone for the help).

@YaroslavNikitenko Collegues are just forced to put up with you during work hours and related to work. Lunch or a party is decidedly not work hours. I bet, if we ask your collegues, they can point to things why they don't want to associate with you.

There are 50 people in that group. And it seems that you are the only one they don't want to spend their lunch time with. Why is that? What is the difference between you and the other 49? If you don't know, have you asked?
